# Displaying string values instead of true and false in Google sheet Query formula data

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a query formula to fetch a table that has the following headers

Date, Details, Amount, **ISDEBIT**

this query displays TRUE or FALSE, I need to display as **DEBITED** for **TRUE** value found in the query data and **CREDITED** for **FALSE** values

I have the query as

```
=query(Recurring!A2:I,"select A, B, C, I")
```

Where I column has only TRUE or FALSE values.

The data is as shown below

[image]

**UPDATE**

The date fields are displaying as below if I use

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(Recurring!A2:I, 
 "select A,B,C,I"), "TRUE", "DEBITED"), "FALSE", "CREDITED"))
```

[image]

Comment: Is Column I on the Recurring tab checkboxes?

Comment: Yes they are checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(Recurring!A2:I, 
 "select A,B,C,I"), "TRUE", "DEBITED"), "FALSE", "CREDITED"))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(Recurring!A2:I, 
 "select A,B,C,I"), TRUE, "DEBITED"), FALSE, "CREDITED"))
```

Comment: When I update with the above formula, it worked but date fields are displaying as shown above in the UPDATE section of the question. can you help out?

Comment: those are valid dates just shown as numeric values. select that column and format it as Date instead of Automatic

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do this, on the Data validations setting for those checkboxes, you can select the whole column of checkboxes and choose Data>Data Validation.  Then you can assign custom "Values" to the True/False output by the checkbox.  That might fix the query output without any other manipulation.